# Kivy: AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__', having unwanted behavioral

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

There's main error

> line 153, in **init**
> self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))
> File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.**getattr**
> AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'

I wanted to add this code which I found, but it's not working. here are my main.py

```
task_list_dialog = None  # Here

# Add the below functions
def show_task_dialog(self):
    if not self.task_list_dialog:
        self.task_list_dialog = MDDialog(
            title="Create Task",
            type="custom",
            content_cls=DialogContent(),
        )

    self.task_list_dialog.open()

    # add this entire function

def on_start(self):
    """Load the saved tasks and add them to the MDList widget when the application starts"""
    try:
        completed_tasks, uncomplete_tasks = db.get_tasks()

        if uncomplete_tasks != []:
            for task in uncomplete_tasks:
                add_task = ListItemWithCheckbox(pk=task[0], text=task[1], secondary_text=task[2])
                self.root.ids.container.add_widget(add_task)

        if completed_tasks != []:
            for task in completed_tasks:
                add_task = ListItemWithCheckbox(pk=task[0], text='[s]' + task[1] + '[/s]',
                                                secondary_text=task[2])
                add_task.ids.check.active = True
                self.root.ids.container.add_widget(add_task)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

def close_dialog(self, *args):
    self.task_list_dialog.dismiss()

def add_task(self, task, task_date):
    '''Add task to the list of tasks'''

    # Add task to the db
    created_task = db.create_task(task.text, task_date)  # Here

    # return the created task details and create a list item
    self.root.get_screen('tasks').ids.container.add_widget(
        ListItemWithCheckbox(pk=created_task[0], text='[b]' + created_task[1] + '[/b]',
                             secondary_text=created_task[2]))  # Here
    task.text = ''
```

class DialogContent(MDBoxLayout):

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    # set the date_text label to today's date when useer first opens dialog box
    self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))

def show_date_picker(self):
    """Opens the date picker"""
    date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
    date_dialog.bind(on_save=self.on_save)
    date_dialog.open()

def on_save(self, instance, value, date_range):
    """This functions gets the date from the date picker and converts its it a
    more friendly form then changes the date label on the dialog to that"""

    date = value.strftime('%A %d %B %Y')
    self.ids.date_text.text = str(date)
```

class ListItemWithCheckbox(TwoLineAvatarIconListItem):
'''Custom list item'''

```
def __init__(self, pk=None, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    # state a pk which we shall use link the list items with the database primary keys
    self.pk = pk

def mark(self, check, the_list_item):
    '''mark the task as complete or incomplete'''
    if check.active == True:
        # add strikethrough to the text if the checkbox is active
        the_list_item.text = '[s]' + the_list_item.text + '[/s]'
        db.mark_task_as_complete(the_list_item.pk)  # here
    else:
        the_list_item.text = str(db.mark_task_as_incomplete(the_list_item.pk))  # Here

def delete_item(self, the_list_item):
    '''Delete the task'''
    self.parent.remove_widget(the_list_item)
    db.delete_task(the_list_item.pk)  # Here
```

class LeftCheckbox(ILeftBodyTouch, MDCheckbox):
"""Custom left container"""

here are my .kv file

```
MDScreen:
  name: "tasks"
  BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
  MDBottomNavigation:

     MDBottomNavigationItem:
        name: 'screen 1'
        icon: 'home-variant-outline'
        MDLabel:
           text: 'Goals in Progress'
           font_name: 'Times'
           font_size: '25sp'
           pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.75, "center_y": .970}
        MDIconButton:
           icon: "square-edit-outline"
           pos_hint: {"x": .869, "y": .001}
           elevation: 18
        DialogContent:
           orientation: "vertical"
           spacing: "10dp"
           size_hint: 1, None
           height: "130dp"

           GridLayout:
              rows: 1

              MDTextField:
                 id: task_text
                 hint_text: "Add Task..."
                 pos_hint: {"center_y": .4}
                 max_text_length: 50
                 on_text_validate: (app.add_task(task_text, date_text.text), app.close_dialog())

              MDIconButton:
                 icon: 'calendar'
                 on_release: root.show_date_picker()
                 padding: '10dp'

           MDLabel:
              spacing: '10dp'
              id: date_text

           BoxLayout:
              orientation: 'horizontal'

              MDRaisedButton:
                 text: "SAVE"
                 on_release: (app.add_task(task_text, date_text.text), app.close_dialog())
              MDFlatButton:
                 text: 'CANCEL'
                 on_release: app.close_dialog()
        ListItemWithCheckbox:
           id: the_list_item
           markup: True

           LeftCheckbox:
              id: check
              on_release:
                 root.mark(check, the_list_item)

           IconRightWidget:
              icon: 'trash-can-outline'
              theme_text_color: "Custom"
              text_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
              on_release:
                 root.delete_item(the_list_item)
```

also I'm having such unwanted behaivior when I run my code by commenting that function.

[unwanted behaivior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqzKA.png) can someone please help with my situation. Thank you!

Comment: The `ids` in a widget are typically not yet assigned when the `__init__()` method is run. You might try to delay accessing `ids` by using something like `Clock.schedule_once()`.

Comment: smth like  " Clock.schedule_once(self.__init__(), 3)" ?

Comment: No, you cannot delay the execution of `__init__()`. Create another method that will do whatever you want with the `ids`, and use `Clock.schedule_once()` to schedule that new method in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: i created almost the same method, but it didn't help `def _otlozhit(self):
        self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))`
or how should I access them?

Comment: And did you use `Clock.schedule_once(self._otlozhit)` in your `__init__()` method?

Comment: yes, it says `line 153, in __init__
     self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`

Comment: The error message says it is still in `__init__()`.

Comment: I accessed class, by replacing it with `MDBoxLayout` but still there are unwanted behaiviors. Where MDialog not shows right

Comment: The `date_text` `id` is defined in the rule for `MDScreen`, so you must access that `id` through the `ids` in that `MDScreen`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class DialogContent(MDBoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_one(self.set_date_text)

    def set_date_text(self., *args):
        self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))
```

Comment: It didn't help says `line 153, in set_date_text
     self.ids.date_text.text = str(datetime.now().strftime('%A %d %B %Y'))
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 964, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'`